# How do I redirect www.mysite.com/facebook to www.facebook.com/myprofile in IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis-7, url-rewriting

As per the title.

For ease of access reasons, I want to get the site to redirect to our Facebook profile when the user goes to a URL on our site. I'm trying to accomplish this in IIS7 on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Do you have isapi_rewrite 3 installed on iis7?

Comment: Yes, I've got that installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have isapi_rewrite 3 you can use htaccess style rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^facebook$ http://facebook.com/profile [NC,L]
```

I'm not really IIS expert but in documentation http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ they say it should work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Limit Redirection to Content in the Destination Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731578%28WS.10%29.aspx)

This will allow you to redirect from www.mysite.com/facebook to www.facebook.com/myprofile

Comment: Won't this just redirect all incoming requests to a single URL? I'm looking to get only one url (/facebook) on the site to redirect to Facebook, not the entire site.

Comment: This will redirect mysite.com/facebook and anything below like mysite.com/facebook/*